# how to get key and value from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is a string like this:

```
var data =  {ListofLayers: "[{"Key":"G1","Value":"park"}]"}
```

I use below code for get key and value:

```
var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
var obj = JSON.parse(Object.values(JSONObject));

$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
     $.each(value, function (key, value) {
        console.log(key + ':' + value);
     });
});
```

but it return

```
Key:G1
Value:park
```

but I expected `G1:park`.

what is wrong?

```js
 var data =  {ListofLayers: '[{"Key":"G1","Value":"park"}]'};


    var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    var obj = JSON.parse(Object.values(JSONObject));
    
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
         $.each(value, function (key, value) {
            console.log(key + ':' + value);
         });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you expect `G1:park`?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` is the same as just `data`.

Comment: Your original `data` assignment is not valid. You need to escape the inside quotes, or use single quotes as the outer delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ypu dont really need the second `each`. You can access the json property as `value["Key"]` or `value.Key`

```js
var JSONObject = {
  ListofLayers: '[{"Key":"G1","Value":"park"}]'
};
var obj = JSON.parse(Object.values(JSONObject));

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value["Key"] + ":" + value["Value"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

See Working Demo :

```js
var data =  {ListofLayers:[{"Key":"G1","Value":"park"}]}


$(document).ready(function(){
$.each(data.ListofLayers, function (key, value) {
    console.log(value.Key+":"+value.Value);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As an alternate, you can also try `Object.values(value).join(':')`

Answer (score 0):

Check this - https://jsfiddle.net/6rLsw56n/

```
var data =  {ListofLayers: '[{"Key":"G1","Value":"park"}]'};
var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
var obj = JSON.parse(Object.values(JSONObject));

$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    var s = '';
    $.each(value, function (key, value) {
        s += (s == '' ? value : (':' + value));       
    });
    console.log(s);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below with javascript ES6.

```js
var data =  {ListofLayers: [{"Key":"G1","Value":"park"}]};

var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
var result ={};
for(let keys of JSONObject.ListofLayers) {
  result = {[keys.Key]: keys.Value};
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rajesh suggested in Dhruvin's answer, the following will work.

```js
var data =  {ListofLayers: '[{"Key":"G1","Value":"park"}]'}
var result = Object.values(JSON.parse(data.ListofLayers)[0]).join(":")

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` to get the values of the keys for the JSON object inside the `ListofLayers` array. Then, this will return an array which you can join using colon (:) like this,

```js
var data = {ListofLayers:[{"Key":"G1","Value":"park"}]}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each(data.ListofLayers, function (key, value) {
      console.log(Object.values(value).join(':'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```